# Office Template no Footer/Header showing

Tags: template

I had to do a Template for Office 2013.

I simply created two pngs one for the header and one for the footer.

Now my client says they are nowhere to be found. If he prints the page the header/footer shows up just fine but in the programm ittself it looks like the header and footer are croped away.

Does anybody has any idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a newer version of Word, you have to double click the header or footer for it to actually show

### Solution

---

Go to

**Word Options > Display >**

and check if **“Show white space between pages in Print Layout view.”**, if its unchecked then check the box label

Comment: What? They are hidden by default? Where would I have to double click? Is there an option to show them be default?

Comment: double click on the space where the header should be

Comment: If that doesnt work then go to Word Options > Display > and check if  **“Show white space between pages in Print Layout view.”**, if its unchecked then check the box label

Comment: Thank you that was it! :) I really have a troubled relationship with MS Word;)

Answer (score 0):

For users with MS Word **before 2007**: just simply click the line in-between a new page and an old page **one** time.

Comment: Can you please add an screenshot and explain a little bit better what you mean? Welcome to GD.SE!